# Azure B2C SAML metadata error AADB2C90020

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

Setting up a "sign in with" connection to a SAML identity provider in a B2C tenant. They have provided a signing certificate that has been successfully imported and is referenced in the custom policy.

The XML metadata is failing to load from
**https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}/{policy}/samlp/metadata?idptp={technical-profile}**

The error encountered is:
**AADB2C90020: The specified signature algorithm 'sha512RSA' is not supported. Expected one of 'sha1RSA' or 'sha256RSA'.**

Maybe this is actually true but it's difficult to believe that the more secure algorithm simply isn't supported. Hoping it's configuration that's at fault.

Was previously working using a self-signed certificate for initial testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Azure AD supports two signing algorithms, or secure hash algorithms (SHAs), to sign the SAML response: `SHA-256` and `SHA-1`.

Azure AD uses SHA-256 as the default algorithm to sign the SAML response. If the application or service provider supports only SHA-1 as the signing algorithm, you can change it by selecting the option in the Signing Algorithm drop-down list.

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean this info from the MS docs is incorrect?: _**XmlSignatureAlgorithm** The method that Azure AD B2C uses to sign the SAML request. This metadata controls the value of the SigAlg parameter (query string or post parameter) in the SAML request. Possible values: Sha256, Sha384, Sha512, or Sha1 (default). Make sure you configure the signature algorithm on both sides with same value. Use only the algorithm that your certificate supports._
[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-identity-provider-technical-profile#metadata)

Comment: Or does it apply to something else?

Comment: Could you check with this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/certificate-signing-options#certificate-signing-algorithms[certificate-signing-algorithms][1]

Comment: This seems essentially correct. The provider's certificate is encrypted using Sha512 which apparently B2C is unable to serve the metadata for. We have gotten around this by serving the metadata ourselves programmatically.